# jquery: animate on height of a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to animate a div from top down. I think the idea is animate the height from 0 to its rendered width.
But before it is shown I don't know the rendered width, how to write the code to animate this?

It's like: `$.animate({"width":"auto"})`

Comment: please clairfy, you're trying to open a div from being hidden from the top of the page? or from the side? trouble figuring out what you're wanting here.  "Height from 0" means from the top, left, right, or bottom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to grab the width using `.width()` like so:

```
var $el = $("#elementID");
$el.animate({height: $el.width()});
```

Answer (score 3):

using .width() will not return the full computed width including the border/padding etc...  for this purpose i would use .outerWidth() and pass the optional true to include the margins.

```
$('element').animate({height: $('element').outerWidth(true)});
```

Comment: Ah but see, setting the height won't set the padding/margins either, so assuming the padding, margins and borders are equal for width and height, using `.width()` would be more correct ;)

Comment: hah, there is a lot of "assumed" to this vague question ;) ... good show though!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#elementID").animate({height:$(this).width()});
```

Comment: @jondavidjohn: I don't understand why you used `$("#elementID")` first and `$(this)` second... they are both in the same scope, and therefore `$(this)` doesn't necessarily refer to `$("#elementID")`